# How to assign variables from text file (batch only!)

Tags: variables, batch-file, text

best user,

I tried to assign variables from a txt file in batch. I have a text file called "Final.txt".

Final.txt:

```
0216027232411405
02160272b6172505
1115fb9c6f423305
1645fb9c6f423305
0000fb9c6f423305
```

script that I tested till now:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Final.txt) do (
   SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
   set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var
```

---

```
(
set /p var1=
set /p var2=
set /p var3=
)<Final.txt
```

---

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f %%x in ("Final.txt") do (
  set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
  set /a Counter+1
  if Counter== 0 goto :EOF
)
set /a NumLines=Counter - 1
echo %Line_1%
pause 

:EOF
Echo please connect a device
pause
exit
```

---

The problem is that the code works, but it only assign the first line of the text file. I want to assign every line in the text file to a variable.Now I only have 5 devices,but in the future iw till expand to more lines. I will do more research, but if you have a solution. Your answers are always welcome!. If I can figure it out I am going to use it in my other script so you are a life saver. I only want to use batch for this.

Comment: your first two scripts are working fine. Your third one has some severe issues. I'd suggest you go with the first one, as it is the most flexible

Comment: But I see only the first line if I echo %var2%,%var3%,%var4% or %var5%. But the first line is assigned to %var1%. The other lines doesn't get assign to the rest of the variables.

Comment: it does behave as intended here with your given data and script. Check your inputfile for hidden characters and proper line endings.

Comment: Your last code is missing an `=` sign. The line `set /a Counter+1` should be `set /a Counter+=1`.

Comment: yes... and the `for` needs "usebackq" because the filename is quoted.

Comment: @Stephan The input file auto generated by an other batch script, Can it be that ? . I will test now for hidden characters and will be back as soon a possible if I know something!

Comment: @Stephan What do you mean by "usebackq"? Can you explain me more about this. Thanks in advance. You all are lifesavers!

Comment: @Stephan I tested and the second line works now, but the other 3 lines it says "echo is off". That means that content in var3 and the rest is emty right? but in the list there are 5 lines without hidden characters